# Divide a space into disjoint sets which has a small measure.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

triple $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ ，$\mathbb P$ is a finite measure.

I have seen a statement in a textbook :

"$\forall \epsilon<\mathbb P(\Omega)$,we can divide $\Omega$ into finite number of disjoint sets in $\mathcal F$,some sets are [atoms](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)) whose measure$> \epsilon,$ and the other sets are not atoms whose measure$<\epsilon$".

How to construct such a partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly true, since $\Omega$ could have countably many (hence not finite) atoms. But the statement is true if you replace the last part of the statement with "and the other sets have measure $\le\epsilon$" (without requiring them not to be atoms). 
First of all, you can identify the atomic part in this way: you say that two atoms $A,B\subseteq\Omega$ are equivalent when $P(A\Delta B)=0$ (check that this is an equivalence relation). There are at most countable equivalence classes, since if you have a collection of measurable subsets $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}$ belonging to different equivalence classes with $P(B_i)\ge\delta$ then for each finite $J\subseteq I$ you have $P(\cup_{i\in J} B_i)=\sum_{i\in J}P(B_i)\ge|J|\delta$ (why?), so $I$ must be finite. 
Then you choose a (at most) countable collection of representatives $\{A_i\}$ for the equivalence classes. You can assume them to be disjoint (why?) and if
you put $\Omega'=\Omega\setminus\cup_i A_i$ then $\Omega'$ has no atoms. 
Since all the $A_i$'s are atoms, you can easily see that now it suffices to split $\Omega'$ into finite subsets of measure $\le\epsilon$. If $P(\Omega')\le\epsilon$, we are already done. Otherwise we will find $S\subset\Omega'$ with $P(S)=\epsilon$ and then, by repeating the process with $\Omega'\setminus S$, we conclude in a finite number of iterations. 
Now there is a standard way to find the required $S$: choose $S_1\subseteq\Omega'$ such that $P(S_1)\le\epsilon$ and $P(S_1)\ge\sup\{P(T):T\subseteq\Omega',P(T)\le\epsilon\}-\frac{1}{2}$. Once you have chosen $S_n$, choose
$S_n\subseteq S_{n+1}\subseteq\Omega'$ such that $P(S_{n+1})\le\epsilon$ and $P(S_{n+1})\ge\sup\{P(T):S_n\subseteq T\subseteq\Omega',P(T)\le\epsilon\}-2^{-(n+1)}$. Since the sequence $S_n$ is increasing, defining $S=\cup_n S_n$ we have $P(S)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(S_n)\le\epsilon$. 
We claim that $P(S)=\epsilon$: otherwise, since $\Omega'\setminus S$ is nonatomic, we can find $U\subseteq\Omega'\setminus S$ such that $P(S)+P(U)\le\epsilon$ and $P(U)>0$. If $N$ is such that $2^{-N}<P(U)$, we have clearly that $S_N\cup U\in\{P(T):S_{N-1}\subseteq T\subseteq\Omega',P(T)\le\epsilon\}$, so that $\sup\{P(T):S_{N-1}\subseteq T\subseteq\Omega',P(T)\le\epsilon\}\ge P(S_N)+P(U)>P(S_N)+2^{-N}$, contradicting the definition of $S_n$. Hence $P(S)=\epsilon$ and we are done.

Comment: According to your construction,S are not atom.

Comment: So what do you mean by atom? If for you an atom is also a singleton, then the statement is not true in general..